# HandsOnTable scrollbars for long datasets

Tags: css, angularjs, handsontable

Knowing that the HandsOnTable plugin controls the tr elements of it's internal table how can scrollbars be reliably added to it?

I have built this HoT code successfully...

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/2vc606wx/

I then implemented that code in my solution and the rendered version of the code produces this...

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/60gphk7j/

The problem, as I see it, is that the HoT table does not have a row for every data item I want to show. In this case it is rendering about 18 tr elements in the table at any time, whereas I know the dataset has 288 items. I know that is a lot.

What I'm looking for is either a CSS solution to ensuring I've got scrollbars on the HoT table or some way to force HoT to load and render all the rows in the table, which I assume will cause scrollbars.

Just to illustrate (and because I have to post some code) the table is rendered as this, which I think is clearly wrong and likely to be causing the scrollbars not to render...

```
<table class="htCore">
                <colgroup>
                  <col style="width: 150px;">
                    <col style="width: 75px;">
                      <col style="width: 75px;">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="" style="height: 25px;">
                      <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">Date</span></div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="">
                      <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">New</span></div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="">
                      <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader">Current</span></div>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">2.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">2.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:05</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">11.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">11.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:10</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">4.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">4.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:15</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">29.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">29.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:20</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">70.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">70.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:25</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">12.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">12.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:30</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">70.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">70.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:35</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">97.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">97.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:40</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">42.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">42.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:45</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">91.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">91.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:50</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">80.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">80.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 00:55</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">17.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">17.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">22.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">22.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:05</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">99.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">99.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:10</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">57.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">57.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:15</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">91.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">91.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:20</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">92.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">92.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:25</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">76.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">76.00</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="htDimmed">21/02/2017 01:30</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric">24.00</td>
                    <td class="htRight htNumeric htDimmed">24.00</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```